# How can use regularization in TensorFlow-Slim?

Tags: tensorflow, regularized, tf-slim

I want use regularization in the my code. I used slim for create conv2d like this:

```
slim.conv2d(input, 256, [1, 1], stride=1,  padding='SAME', scope='conv1')
```

How can I add regularization to this?
and how can I used it for regularize my loss?

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/contrib/slim/README.md#scopes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah just can just add a parameter

```py
weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(0.001)
```

or your can use slim.arg_scope to set the regularization for several layers:

```py
with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d],
                    padding='SAME',
                    weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(0.001)):
      net = slim.conv2d(input, 256, [1, 1], scope='conv1')
      net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, [1, 1], scope='conv2')
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But how can I used `regularizer` for loss function?

Comment: you can use `slim.losses.get_regularization_losses()` to gather all the regularization losses you have defined in your model.